# Select statement inside Concatenate (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have complex Select statement in Oracle, with Case When conditions and they select all Concatenate values.
So something similar to this:

```
END
END
FROM something
...
```

What I need is to put Other value from other table instead of My Value in concatenate.
So Instead of (My Value) I would have:

```
(Select textValue from textView A where A.textID = '395')
```

If I run this statement alone, it will take out one exact value I want. However if I put it instead of (My Value) into concatenate it gives me error: ora-00936 missing expression 
(Yes '395' is string in that other table)

Any Ideas please?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Looks like Oracle -- `||` is the concatenation operator. But it would certainly help to tag the question with the DBMS.

Comment: Yes sorry, I changed OP. It`s Oracle.

Comment: And what is the error?  And, can you edit the query and show the code that is actually failing?

Comment: The worst thing is I can`t post the query since it`s code from work, and I don`t want to get into trouble. Also the Query is huge, I mean Huge. But the Important thing is in OP what I try to achieve. Also this is the error: ora-00936 missing expression

Comment: @AndrewLeach: `||` is the concatenation operator defined in the SQL standard. So `||` only implies a standard compliant DBMS with regards to string concatenation it does not imply Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inline views inside the case clause in Oracle.   Isn't that what you are trying to do?  "Missing expression" error is probably a missing bracket or some similar code error.

```
select case object_type
          when 'TABLE' then
             'select * from ' || object_name
          when 'SYNONYM' then
             'describe ' || object_name
          when 'PACKAGE' then
             (select to_char (count (*))
                from user_source s
               where s.type = o.object_type and s.name = o.object_name)
          else
             (select object_type from dual)
       end
          as objects
  from user_objects o
```

Or simply create a function that returns that does this for you and call it.

```
create function gettextval (p_textid in varchar2)
    return varchar2 is
    l_returnval   varchar2 (32767);
begin
    select text_val
      into l_returnval
      from v_texts s
     where s.text_id = p_textid;

    return l_returnval;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        return p_textid;
end;
```

In this example I make it return the input string of nothing is found.

Then you can reference the function in your previous select.

```
' || gettextval('395') || '
```

Comment: This is the first thing that worked. But it works only with ' || (select TO_CHAR (count (*))
                from V_TEXTS s
               where s.TEXT_ID = '395') || '   it doesn`t work when I put the actual column I want instead of TO_CHAR (count (*)) which I don`t need.

Comment: Make sure that you cast it to the same datatype as other rows are returning.  For instance in my example, the SQL returns an error if you remove "to_char" since all other rows are returning text (varchar2) the SQL engine doesn't expect a number.

Comment: ' || (select CAST(TEXT_VALUE AS NVARCHAR2(255)) from V_TEXTS V where V.TEXT_ID = '395') || '    Still character mismatch. No idea what`s causing it now.

Comment: If to_char(count(*)) worked before then the results are being cast as char or varchar2.  Stick with to_char().

Answer (score 0):

can you post you query with the "select text" bit inside?

When use case->when i do like that:

```
SELECT
  CASE A.LIST_TYPE_CD
    WHEN '1' THEN '<A HREF="censured?thresholdId=censured' || GET_SITE_SUFFIX() || chr(38) || 'task=runSQL' || chr(38) || 'parseParams=true' || chr(38) || 'list_id=' ||  A.LIST_ID || chr(38) || 'list_name=' || A.LIST_NAME ||
'">' || (Select textValue from textView A where A.textID = '395') || '</A>'
    WHEN '3' THEN '<A HREF=censured' || GET_SITE_SUFFIX() || chr(38) || 'task=runSQL' || chr(38) || 'parseParams=true' || chr(38) || 'list_id=' || A.LIST_ID ||
    '">' || (Select textValue from textView B where B.textID = '395') || '</A>'
END
FROM something A
```

Comment: Yeah heh I could use conc. even there, though now i get:                 ora-12704 character set mismatch

Comment: `CAST` the selected `textValue` to NVARCHAR. Also, be sure your little select returns only one row..